# Codeigniter restclient not working

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, curl

I am trying to install the CodeIgniter RESTClient and RESTServer libraries for my solution. ([philsturgeon-codeigniter-restclient](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient)  and [chriskacerguis-codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) ).

I managed to get the rest server up and running, but I am encountering issues with the rest client.

These are the steps I did to come where I am now:

1. Copy the Rest.php file (downloaded from GitHub) and put it in the libraries folder
2. Download the [Curl library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl/tree/master/libraries) and put it in libraries
3. Modified the code in Rest.php to uncomment `$this->_ci->load->library('curl');` (if I hover over the usages of the curl library in this file I get the following message):

> Field 'curl' not found in CI_Controller

4. I create a new controller called "Restclient" to test my API. In this controller I created the following method:

   ```
   function rest_client_example($id)
   {
       $this->load->library('rest', array(
           'server' => 'localhost/codeigniter/api/users/'
       ));

       $user = $this->rest->get('volunteer', array('id' => $id), 'json');

       var_dump($user);
   }
   ```

Browsing to http://localhost/codeigniter/api/restclient/rest_client_example/25 then gives me

```
D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controllers\api\Restclient.php:36:null
```

When executing the following code instead of the above, I do get a correct result:

```
    $this->load->library('curl');

    $t = $this->curl->simple_get('api/users/volunteer', array('id'=>$id));
    var_dump($t);
```

So I do know that the curl is working.

My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the loading of the curl library?

Comment: what if you do `$autoload['libraries'] = array('curl','rest');` in `autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is specific to the Libraries mentioned here. Have you tried anything else?  I've had really good success with guzzle http

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle